# Парсинг файла в массив структур

Tags: c, парсер, структуры

Нужно прочитать файл и в массив структур загнать значения со сцены типа файла "sphere"
Тип фигуры, центр, радиус, направление, цвет.

В файле sphere:

```
cam: [position_vector]
sphere: [position_vector] [rotation_vector] [radius] [color]
light: [position_vector]
```

и вернуть массив структур.

```cpp
#ifndef RTV_H
#define RTV_H
// #include "../libft/libft.h"
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_vec3
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}               t_vec3;

typedef struct s_object
{
    int type;
    t_vec3 origin;
    t_vec3 direction;
    double radius;
    int angle;
    int color;
}              t_object;
typedef struct s_camera
{
    t_vec3 position;
    double fov;
    double imageAspectRotation;
}               t_camera;

#endif
```

сам файл: между значениями табы, а не пробелы.

```
camera: 0.0,0.0,200.0       none        none        none
sphere: 0.0,0.0,3.0         0,0,0       1.0         0xff0000
ligth:  80.0,100.0,200.0    none        none        none
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Читайте. Вникайте. Исправляйте вопрос, пока его не закрыли.

Comment: Исправил, чтобы людям было хоть что-то понятно. Объясню: 1) Разметку "код" нужно применять только к коду или, в крайнем случае, к каким-то данным, но никак не ко всему тексту вопроса. 2) **Никогда не вставляйте код и вообще что-либо по ссылке**, т.к. вопросы на SO призваны помогать людям ещё долгое время, а информация по ссылке может стать недоступной; лучше копируйте код прямо в вопрос. 3) Если представляете свой код, скажите, что с ним не так, почему он работает не так, как Вам нужно, и что Вы от него ждёте. Тогда Вам смогут ответить.

Comment: совсем не понятно, как именно данные хранятся в файле. [position_vector] - это три числа через пробел, запятую или слеши.

Comment: если файлы ты создаешь сам, то совет не использовать CSV и прочие текстовые форматы без "метаданных". а пользоваться чем-то более удобным например JSON, в С++ есть разные реализации например https://rapidjson.org/